# having trouble understanding how to use json.net

Tags: c#

I've been reading for hours and still can't figure out how to use this
under my button I have

```
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        Uri uri = new Uri("url");
        string json = wc.DownloadString(uri);
        var a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

and the classes

```
    public class Shares
    {
        public int valid { get; set; }
        public int invalid { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int donate_percent { get; set; }
        public int is_anonymous { get; set; }
        public string username { get; set; }
    }

    public class Transactions
    {
        public double Credit { get; set; }
        public double Debit_MP { get; set; }
        public double Fee { get; set; }
        public int TXFee { get; set; }
    }

    public class Data
    {
        public string username { get; set; }
        public Shares shares { get; set; }
        public int hashrate { get; set; }
        public string sharerate { get; set; }
        public Transactions transactions { get; set; }
    }

    public class Getuserstatus
    {
        public string version { get; set; }
        public double runtime { get; set; }
        public Data data { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public Getuserstatus getuserstatus { get; set; }
    }
```

I did a messagebox to check the string from the URL and all the data is there but it doesn't put it into the fields when I call them they're all empty

```
        Shares Share = new Shares();
        textBox1.Text += "Username: " + Share.username;
```

edit:
ok I got it working the a.getsuerstatus.data.shares.username is not valid in the api I don't know why jsontocsharp site added it but all the data is there username is actually a.getuserstatus.data.username thank you all for the help or I would have still be trying to call data using Shares Share = new Shares()

Comment: Can you post sample json from the API? If class definitions don't correctly match the schema of the json it won't work. I can correct them if that is the case :)

Comment: Can you share the json string ?

Comment: {"getuserstatus":{"version":"1.0.0","runtime":201.36690139771,"data":{"username":"snow","shares":{"valid":0,"invalid":0,"donate_percent":0,"is_anonymous":0},"hashrate":0,"sharerate":"0.0000","transactions":{"Credit":5592.5516587,"Debit_MP":5456.48342204,"Fee":27.96275827,"TXFee":100}}}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code:

```
Shares Share = new Shares();
textBox1.Text += "Username: " + Share.username;
```

creates a new instance of an object of type `Shares` which has the `username` property initialized to an empty string.

There is no connection with the json-formatted text you'd like to parse.

The method that you are using to parse the json string: `var a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);` expects to generate an object of type `RootObject`

You will want to set the Text property of `textbox1` equal to the corresponding `Shares` object that is deserialized into `a`.

```
 textbox1.Text = a.getUserStatus.data.shares.username;
```

Comment: I tried this textBox1.Text += "Username: '" + a.getuserstatus.data.shares.username + "'"; and I get Username: '' in the textbox

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't the deserialization, it's this;

```
   Shares Share = new Shares();
    textBox1.Text += "Username: " + Share.username;
```

which instead needs to be

```
    textBox1.Text += "Username: " + a.getUserStatus.data.username;
```

`a` is the object instantiated by json.NET. You need to go through all the indirection to access the value of `username`, not just allocated a new `Share` instance and access it's username, the two references point to entirely different objects.

Comment: I tried this
     textBox1.Text += "Username: '" + a.getuserstatus.data.shares.username + "'";
and I get Username: '' in the textbox

Comment: @MichaelPinkiePieMarshall I have a theory, are you sure you don't want `a.getUserStatus.data.username`? `data` has a `username` property which is set in the json example you posted. I don't see one for `share`, I was just basing that off your class definitions. I edited my post, I think that will work. If not I'd double check your model against the json and make sure it matches exactly.